# I’m getting an error while importing Razorpay in Django

Tags: django, django-views, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am integrating the Razorpay payment gateway in a Django project, but I am getting an error while importing razorpay as:

> Import razorpay could not be resolved

#### Code

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import razorpay  # Here I am getting an error

from .models import coffee
```

This is my full code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import razorpay

from .models import coffee
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
    Name = request.POST.get("Name")
    Amount = int(request.POST.get("Amount")) * 100
    client = razorpay.Client(auth=            ("rzp_test_YhfEhfejrkkjdkfju","t5MRPkjfijdh23845kejkej"))
    payment = client.order.create({'Amount':Amount, 'currency':'INR','payment_capture':'1'})
    print(payment)
    Coffee = coffee(Name=Name, Amount=Amount , payment_id = payment['id'] )
    return render(request,'index.html',{'payment':payment})

return render(request,'index.html')

def success(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    a = request.POST
    print(a)
return render(request,"success.html")
```

This is my terminal output:

```
File "D:\Project 3\payment\paymentapp\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
from .import views
File "D:\Project 3\payment\paymentapp\views.py", line 3, in <module>
import razorpay
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'razorpay'
```

Comment: Are you in your virtualenv with that installed?

Comment: yes i am working in virtualenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few basic things you have to know before using the Razorpay gateway in your project. First is your amount. It is considered in [paisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paisa), so you have to multiply it by 100 to convert it in to rupee. As I can see, you are multiplying by 10 to amount next.

If you want to use Razorpay, you must use:

```
pip install razorpay
```

And I will also recommend you to read the full documentation for using it, because it seems that you are missing a lot of things. Like you have to write JavaScript code handle, etc.:

*[About Standard Web Checkout Integration](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard/)*

Comment: i install razorpay by pip install razorpay and  after that i import razorpay but error is there.

Comment: How was such an incomprehensible answer ever accepted and upvoted? Try to make sense of [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68924614/1)  (like in actually reading it and understanding it), with *** ***all*** *** punctuation left out. Or [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68924614/2) for that matter. It is ***infuriating***.

Answer (score 0):

type deactivate on the terminal
then pip install razorpay
then python manage.py run server

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35716456)